# Rails 3, how to move jquery script to application.js file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following script at the bottom of my form:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<% end %>

<script>
<% auth_params = Panda.signed_params('post', "/videos.json") %>
jQuery("#returned_video_id").pandaUploader(<%=raw auth_params.to_json %>, {
upload_progress_id: 'upload_progress'
});
</script>
```

I've tried moving this script to my application.js file, but no matter which way I seem to tweak it, it doesn't work. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

it contains ruby code. rename your application.js to application.js.erb. it should work.

Comment: yeah. it cannot instantly move to application.js because auth_params are not available yet in application.js. try using ajax in your application.js. `$.ajax({url: "your_controller/your_action.js"})`. add respond `format.js` in your_controller then put your script in `your_view/your_action.js.erb`. the script may not in application.js, but at least it removed from _form.erb

Answer (score 0):

You just create a .js file in app/assets/javascripts and it will become part of application.hs, provided you have a

```
require_tree .
```

as part of application.js

Refer to [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: as noted above, this script contains ruby code, so it doesn't work in a js file.